# Process dialog in service class in android

Tags: android, service, handler

I am  trying  to do Run the process dialog when service running Time. i am using hanler to running the process dialog in my service class. that time i am having following issuse. please any one help me.....

**Logcat**

```
04-16 16:43:57.691: W/dalvikvm(395): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
04-16 16:43:57.813: E/AndroidRuntime(395): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-16 16:43:57.813: E/AndroidRuntime(395): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
04-16 16:43:57.813: E/AndroidRuntime(395):  at android.view.ViewRoot.setView(ViewRoot.java:531)
04-16 16:43:57.813: E/AndroidRuntime(395):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:177)
04-16 16:43:57.813: E/AndroidRuntime(395):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
04-16 16:43:57.813: E/AndroidRuntime(395):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
04-16 16:43:57.813: E/AndroidRuntime(395):  at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:107)
04-16 16:43:57.813: E/AndroidRuntime(395):  at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:95)
04-16 16:43:57.813: E/AndroidRuntime(395):  at com.appname.notification.StartNotification$1.handleMessage(StartNotification.java:235)
04-16 16:43:57.813: E/AndroidRuntime(395):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-16 16:43:57.813: E/AndroidRuntime(395):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-16 16:43:57.813: E/AndroidRuntime(395):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
04-16 16:43:57.813: E/AndroidRuntime(395):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-16 16:43:57.813: E/AndroidRuntime(395):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-16 16:43:57.813: E/AndroidRuntime(395):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
04-16 16:43:57.813: E/AndroidRuntime(395):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
04-16 16:43:57.813: E/AndroidRuntime(395):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-16 16:43:57.813: E/AndroidRuntime(395): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-16 16:43:57.813: E/AndroidRuntime(395): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
04-16 16:43:57.813: E/AndroidRuntime(395):  at android.view.ViewRoot.setView(ViewRoot.java:531)
04-16 16:43:57.813: E/AndroidRuntime(395):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:177)
04-16 16:43:57.813: E/AndroidRuntime(395):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
04-16 16:43:57.813: E/AndroidRuntime(395):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
04-16 16:43:57.813: E/AndroidRuntime(395):  at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:107)
04-16 16:43:57.813: E/AndroidRuntime(395):  at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:95)
04-16 16:43:57.813: E/AndroidRuntime(395):  at com.appname.notification.StartNotification$1.handleMessage(StartNotification.java:235)
04-16 16:43:57.813: E/AndroidRuntime(395):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-16 16:43:57.813: E/AndroidRuntime(395):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-16 16:43:57.813: E/AndroidRuntime(395):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
04-16 16:43:57.813: E/AndroidRuntime(395):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-16 16:43:57.813: E/AndroidRuntime(395):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-16 16:43:57.813: E/AndroidRuntime(395):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
04-16 16:43:57.813: E/AndroidRuntime(395):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
04-16 16:43:57.813: E/AndroidRuntime(395):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**Service class.**

```
public class StartNotification extends Service {

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    String notification_Url = KP.KPURL.NOTIFICATION;
    public ProgressDialog pDialog;
    public Message m = new Message();
    private static final int PROCESS_START = 0;
    private static final int PROCESS_STOP = 1;

    // "2014-02-04 00:00:00"
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        processLoading();
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }
public void storelocalDB() {
// my logic
}

    private void processLoading() {
        m.what = PROCESS_START;
        handler.sendMessage(m);
        storelocalDB();
        m = new Message();
        m.what = PROCESS_STOP;
        handler.sendMessage(m);
    }
private Handler handler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
            case PROCESS_START:
                pDialog = ProgressDialog.show(getApplicationContext(),
                        " Please wait...!", "Loading...", true, false);
                break;
            case PROCESS_STOP:
                if (pDialog.isShowing()) {
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to make a new object first :

```
ProgressDialog pdialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
```

I did not see that you created an object.

Comment: now i got diffrent issue "Unable to instantiate service com.appname.notification.StartNotification: java.lang.NullPointerException"

Comment: May you post whole logcat exception and line where NullPointerException is thrown?

Comment: your code ProgressDialog pdialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity()); but i changed ProgressDialog pdialog = new ProgressDialog(getApplicationContext());.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can show ProgressDialog from service.The better option is you have to show dialog in activity from where you start service and register receiver from there.And when service stop send broadcast to the activity and finish the running Progress Dialog.